# Notice to proposer of edits

Tags: feature-request

I have seen a couple recent edit proposals from people who didn't have the rep to really make one that added something significant to the original post.  The addition was correct and helpful, but I wouldn't have wanted to put it over OP's signature.  Making it a comment or an answer seemed more appropriate to me.  I would like to have a way to reply to the edit proposer with a suggestion like this.  I tried making a comment to the question with the @ notification to the proposer, but don't know if this works.  I suspected that the edit proposer might be the same as OP and suggested a request that accounts be merged.

Comment: There is a 'custom reject'. Not sure if the proposer gets notified. But he can see the reason I think, if he clicks on some link somewhere!

Comment: @Aryabhata:  Thanks.  I have used the custom reject and explained it.  I didn't know that the proposer saw that.

Comment: Related feature requests on Meta Stack Exchange: [Allow failed editors be @replied to](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/198977) and [Decision on rejected edits should be displayed as a notification to the editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/120624) (the latter is marked [meta-tag:status-completed]).